# How to make windows os append a numeric index to filename choosen if file already exists

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, microsoft-excel, file-management

I am creating a lot of microsoft excel files and backing them up to amazon storage.When i am creating the files,usually on my laptop or desktop computer,i may forget what the filename i had given any one file and so giving the same filename to a new file is highly likely.

To go around that problem that i deem may lead to loss of important data by way of file being replaced by a new file with identical filename,i propose to force windows to automatically give a file a numeric index to a filename that is found to duplicate on file creation time.

Is there a way i can switch on this behaviour on windows os?.

My laptop runs windows 8 64 bit but i also have various office machines running microsoft windows xp and windows 7.

Comment: How are you creating the files?  Copy-paste in Windows handles the issue you've described, but I'm guessing you're doing something different . . .

Comment: Yes,what i am doing is a bit different.I am getting the excel sheet from a web application and downloading clicking the download button.My web browser is firefox.

Comment: You're downloading files via firefox and saving them directly to amazon cloud? Or are they going to the HDD and then being reuploaded, using a sync or manually?

Comment: I am downloading manually to hdd then sync them with simple storage.